# Closed form of :$\int\tan ( e^{-x²})\ d x$ Over reals

Tags: integration, trigonometry, closed-form

I w'd surprised if this integral $\int\tan ( e^{-x²})\ d x$ has a closed form since :$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty }\tan ( e^{-x²})\ d x$ is assumed as a constant by [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(++(+tan(e%5E(-x%C2%B2)))),+x%3D+-infty+to+infty) and [The inverse calculator](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc) didn't  give me any thing  such that it's value is $2.27591....$ 
 ,  then any way to show that if it has a closed form , or it is just a constant ?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that:

$$\tan (x)=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{\left((-1)^n \left(4^n-16^n\right) B_{2 n}\right) x^{2 n-1}}{\Gamma (1+2 n)}
$$
so:

$$\int \tan \left(\exp \left(-x^2\right)\right) \, dx=\\\int \left(\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n \left(4^n-16^n\right) e^{-(-1+2 n) x^2} B_{2 n}}{\Gamma (1+2 n)}\right) \,
   dx=\\\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \int \frac{(-1)^n \left(4^n-16^n\right) e^{-(-1+2 n) x^2} B_{2 n}}{\Gamma (1+2 n)} \, dx=\\\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{1+n} 2^{-1+2 n}
   \left(-1+4^n\right) \sqrt{\pi } B_{2 n} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{-1+2 n} x\right)}{\sqrt{-1+2 n} \Gamma (1+2 n)}$$

and for define integral:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{1+n} 4^n \left(-1+4^n\right) \sqrt{\pi } B_{2 n}}{\sqrt{-1+2 n} \Gamma (1+2 n)}\approx 2.27591$$

where: $B_{2n}$ is Bernoulli numbers.

I doubt there's a closed form for the Sum.